# Converting vector<unsigned char> to const unsigned char*

Tags: c++, opencv, casting, char, base64

I'm trying to create an application where a Mat image in OpenCV is encoded using `cv::imencode` to a base64 string. For this I must convert a `vector<unsigned char>` to a `const unsigned char*`.

How can I do this?

```
vector<unsigned char> buffer;

vector<int> compression_params;
compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PXM_BINARY);
compression_params.push_back(0);

if(!cv::imencode(".ppm", desc, buffer, compression_params)){
    printf("Image encoding failed");
}

// This generates a error
string output = base64_encode(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
printf("Output: %s", output.c_str());
```

This is the error I get: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x2ffd7000)`

## Update

---

Now it doesn't generate any error's anymore, but somewhere in the conversion something goes wrong; the output isn't what the same as the input after I decoded it, it mostly consists of A character. This is the current script:

```
vector<unsigned char> buffer;

vector<int> compression_params;
compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PXM_BINARY);
compression_params.push_back(1);

if(!cv::imencode(".pgm", desc, buffer, compression_params)){
    printf("Image encoding failed");
}

string output = base64_encode(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
printf("Output: %s", output.c_str());
```

*I don't think this should be another question because my guess is that the conversion between vector to const unsigned char messes the result up; the [base64_encode](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/common/base64.html) worked the previous time.*

Comment: `buffer.data()` is already a `const unsigned char*`, so there's no need to `reinterpret_cast` it (if you're not using a C++11 compiler, you can do `&buffer[0]`). Also, posting your actual error message would be *very* helpful... otherwise, people are guessing at what the problem is.

Comment: I get this error when I remove it: `malloc: *** error for object 0x41444967: pointer being freed was not allocated` and when I use the `&buffer[0]` I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x2ffd7000)`

Comment: Also, I wouldn't do `.c_str()`... just assign the `string` to the `string`. I wouldn't be surprised if the `string`'s memory returned by `base64_encode` was getting freed (since it's a temporary) when you were trying to do the assignment (I could be wrong on this, but I still wouldn't call `.c_str()`, as it prevents proper move semantics).

Comment: Sorry that was an editing mistake, I didn't copy and paste that part; it should be a `const char*`.

Comment: Are you getting a compile error, or a runtime error.  And what is the base64_encode function?  Is it yours, is it from a project where you can show us the documentation?

Comment: I am getting a runtime error, it only happens when the function it is in is called. I am using the base64 functions from here: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/common/base64.html

Comment: Have you used a debugger and found the line of code where the problem occurs?

Comment: Yes I did, it was on the line that calls `base64_encode`

Answer (score 3):

One major problem is:

```
const char* s = base64_encode(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(buffer.data()), buffer.size()).c_str();
```

Here, the `base64_encode` funciton is returning a `std::string`.  You are then calling the `c_str()` method, which returns a pointer to the underlying buffer.  HOWEVER, the `std::string` then immediately goes out of scope, leaving you with a dangling pointer.

Furthermore, the reinterpret_cast should not be needed at all.  You're running into Undefined Behavior due to the dangling pointer, which has nothing to do with the cast.

You should change it to

```
std::string s = base64_encode(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
```

Comment: I removed the `reinterpret_cast` and created a new `string` variable, but both didn't work; I still get the same error. After that I changed the compression parameter to write to binary; now I don't get any more errors but the string that is generated isn't correct.

Comment: @ThomasVersteeg:  Okay, what is 'cv::imencode(".pgm", desc, buffer, compression_params)', and can you show us the documentation, in particular how it fills in the buffer.  Also, can you just insert a cout of buffer.size() prior to the call, to make sure that it's what you want.

Comment: Here is the documentation on cv::imencode: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html and where should I cout the buffer.size() to?